# Nvidia 2D surround not showing up in control panel

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I hooked up my old monitor today and now want to configure it so that I can use both of my monitors in games.

I've Googled the issue and found that one is supposed to configure Surround in the Nvidia control panel. However this option is not showing up for me:

[image].

I've set both monitors to the same refresh rate and resolution and I'm running Windows 7 so that should not be the source of my problem.

My system specs:

```
Mainboard GA-970A-D3
CPU       AMD Phenom II X6 1055T
GPU       nVidia GeForce GTX 570
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need two graphics cards to use multiple monitors in games?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the display driver installed?

Comment: Yes I do but this _should_ work on older versions too.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least three monitors to activate Nvidia surround.thats why there is no icon to activate. Just imagine where the cross hair would be in shooting games in a two monitor setup!

Comment: Really? Of cause it wouldn't work for shooters but it would work reasonably well for strategy games and the like. Is there another method to get this working anyways?

Answer (score -1):

It's not just that, you need at least two GTX 570 in SLI mode for it to work. If you just want one graphics card, you will need at least a GTX 650.

Comment: It’s not just *what*?